# Can a ship fly below an island, or fall onto one?

Tags: savage-worlds, flight, sundered-skies

In Sundered Skies, the core book states (on page 3) that

> Unknown forces prevent ships from flying over islands unless they travel at least a mile above it. A ship may approch an island's edge but for reasons not fully understood, they are unable to sail closed without also sailing higher.

I find this restriction quite useful as it would feel strange to be able to steer a ship right into a city or something.

But apart from this "unknown forces [...] not fully understood" makes me feel a bit uncomfortable, the rule leaves some questions open: Can a ship fly right *below* an island? And if damaged while flying high above, can it fall into the island? Or is it somehow pushed to the edge while falling down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My in-game understanding is whatever force(s) keep the islands themselves afloat tends to locally mess up the mechanism that keeps ships afloat. In the game I played in, this meant you could only go so far (not very) over an island before you basically fully lost control of your ship and crashed.

To answer your questions more directly:

Yes, a ship can fly right below an island, but good luck keeping your masts away from stalactites.

No, the magic involved doesn't need to actively repel things (though your DM may rule differently). If you were a mile up and dropped a boulder, it wouldn't deflect off the island or not depending on whether it was shaped like a ship or not.